# Is it possible that "du -ks *" answer is plain wrong?

Tags: ubuntu, disk-usage

On a Ubuntu 18.04 I was investigating discrepancies on disk space reports. Doing a `du -ks *` to see space on subdirectories, I narrowed down on the discrepancy, but when doing the same command again, one of the directories returned a size double the number given before. This is small (30M instead of 15M), but it might have an impact on my trust to the du answer.

All this happened without a warning or an error.
Is it possible that du gets the data so wrong and does not say anything?

Cheers, hubert

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely seeing the effect of hard links.

The `du` utility will only ever calculate and show you the size taken by each inode once, even if that inode has more than one associated name in one or several directories.

Example:

```
$ tree
.
|-- dir-a
|   `-- file1
`-- dir-b
    `-- file1

2 directories, 2 files
```

```
$ ls -li dir-*/file1
25732 -rw-r--r--  2 myself  wheel  8757248 Dec  9 08:33 dir-a/file1
25732 -rw-r--r--  2 myself  wheel  8757248 Dec  9 08:33 dir-b/file1
```

The files `dir-a/file1` and `dir-b/file1` are two names for the same file. Notice the inode number in the output of `ls -li` (first column).

```
$ du -h dir-*
8.4M    dir-a
1.0K    dir-b
```

```
$ du -h dir-b
8.4M    dir-b
```

With the first command, the size of the `dir-b` directory is only a single kilobyte, but running the second command shows it as 8.4 megabytes. This is because in the first command, the file `file1` in `dir-a` had already been seen so it was not included in the calculations for the size of `dir-b` when the same inode was seen again.